# Область видимости Javascript внутри фрейма

Tags: javascript, iframe

Есть ли какая либо уловка или ограничение с областью видимости для javascript кода, который подключен внутри iframe к внешнему фрейму?

Comment: если домен одинаковый - то из одной ОВ можно попасть в другую

Answer (score 0, accepted):

iframe - отдельная страница, выведенная при помощи браузера внутри основной. Если вы хотите использовать один скрипт на каждой из этих страниц, подключить его придется в обеих. Если же нужно, чтобы передавались параметры из одной страницы в другую, кидайте JSON-запросы из дочерней страницы в родительскую, или не используйте iframe, а подгружайте контент через граббер — в этом случае скрипт будет работать как единое целое.